# Why does the C++20 range concept specify apparently misleading requirements?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

I'm struggling to satisfy a C++20 concept for my class.

```
struct C1
{
    int* begin();
    int* end();
};

static_assert(std::ranges::range<C1>);  // Compiles fine

struct C2 {};

namespace std::ranges    // (A)
{
    auto begin(C2&);
    auto end(C2&);
}

static_assert(std::ranges::range<C2>);  // Fails to compile
```

The `std::ranges::range<>` concept is defined as follows:

```
template <class _Rng>
concept range = requires(_Rng& __r) {
  std::ranges::begin(__r);
  std::ranges::end(__r);
};
```

Taking this literally instructs me to declare the functions (A) above.
But these doen't help.
On the other hand, defining the two member functions as in class `C1` **does** work.
My problem is that I just don't see the semantic connection between the requirement imposed by the concept and the solution that helps for class `C1`. It tells me to do one thing when in fact I need to do another thing.

Please provide some explanation for this.

Background: In my production code, my class *does* define a `begin()` and `end()` function that return an iterator each. But the `range` concept is not satisfied with these definitions and fails to show me why.

See the full example on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fKT4vPz6a)

Answer (score 8):

`std::ranges::begin` is a customization point object; it's not a function you can overload. And even if `begin` were a proper function, you cannot insert overloads of functions into the `std` namespace or any sub-namespace (you can specialize templates in `std`, but only if it involves at least one user-defined type).

The way to conform to `std::ranges::begin` is by [following its rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/begin). After checking that the given range type is an array (for which it has specialized logic), it will look for, in order:

- A member `begin` function returning an iterator.
- A `begin` function which can be found by argument-dependent lookup (ie: `begin(range_object)`) which returns an iterator.

So if you want to make a type into a range without adding members, you must use the latter: put a `begin` function in the same namespace as the type in question. Also, it needs to return a type that can be verified to be an iterator.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, not an error, to add to `namespace std` (outside the permitted exceptions), so "no error" isn't *wrong* on the part of the compiler

Comment: @Caleth: The error part is about `ranges::begin` not being a function but an object. There should have been an error when you tried to overload it.

Comment: `ranges::begin` is defined in a unspecified inline namespace, the definitions could coexist outside of `std`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to add overloads in the `std` namespace.

If `C2` itself does not contain `begin()`/`end()` member functions,
you can add a free function named `begin()/end()` under the same namespace to obtain its iterator and sentinel, making it model the `range` concept, for example:

```
struct C2 {};

int* begin(C2&);
int* end(C2&);

static_assert(std::ranges::range<C2>);
```

(A similar example in the standard is `directory_iterator`, which has free function [`begin()/end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/begin) overloads)

Comment: -*You are not allowed to add overloads in the std namespace.* Not exactly; to provide formatting for your own class, you need to specialize `std::formatter`.

Comment: @Red.Wave Specializing `std::formatter` is not adding overloads to the std namespace.

Answer (score 0):

@Nicol Bolas, @Caleth, @康桓瑋: Thanks for your answers and explanations.
I really need to fully grasp how these customization points really work.

You're telling me that `begin()` is supposed to return an iterator.
But again, I don't see that requirement in the *definition* of concept `range`.
I'd expect to find something along the lines of:

```
template <class _Rng>
concept range = requires(_Rng& __r) {
    { begin(__r) } -> std::input_or_output_iterator;
    { end(__r) } -> std::input_or_output_iterator;
};
```

But at least the documentation, you referred me to, states this requirement.

After recursively digging into concept `std::input_or_output_iterator`,
I managed to define a class that satisfies this concept.

For reference, this is a minimal implementation that satisfies all requirements.
See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/3nWe1EnqP):

```
#include <ranges>

struct V {};

struct C
{
    struct I 
    {
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = V*;
        const value_type operator*() const;
        I& operator++();
        I operator++(int);
        // This operator makes C::I a valid iterator for std::ranges::range<>
        friend bool operator==(const I&, const I&);
    };

    I begin();
    I end();
};

static_assert(std::input_or_output_iterator<C::I>);

// This assertion requires operator I::operator==() to be defined.
static_assert(std::ranges::range<C>);

int main() {}
```

At some point, I found a hint that `friend bool operator==(const I&, const I&);` is required, too. But I forgot to note down the source.